# Is there any "simultaneous-turn" based game where all players play till the end of the game?

Tags: recommendations, diplomacy

I use to play diplomacy with my work mates, the good thing of this game is that we can play with long turns (36 hours) so anyone can play whenever they can, and the turn is resolved when the time passes or when everybody has declared their movements. We use http://webdiplomacy.net/ to manage the movements.

The bad thing of diplomacy is that the usual thing is that around mid-game some players are destroyed and they stop playing, having to wait till the end of the game (what can mean even weeks) to start playing again in a new game. Playing more than one game in parallel is not an option, we tried that and is a bit crazy, and requires much more time every day.

Do you know any game with similar turn-based rules but where the players can keep playing along the whole game?

**UPDATE:** After some discussion, more explicit requirements:

1. All turns are played asynchronously (each player can choose all
   their actions for the turn at any time).
2. All actions of each turn are played simultaneously.
3. All players can play along the whole game (no player elimination).

Nice to have:

1. During the turn time some type of negotiation is encouraged between players.
2. Web version.
3. Game for more than 4 players.

As an example, Diplomacy would fit with all requirements except the third one, and also with the nices to have.

Comment: [Republic of Rome?](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1513/the-republic-of-rome)

Comment: Does the game need to be able to be played asynchronously? As an example, would [7 wonders](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/68448/7-wonders) (a card drafting game) satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Good one, I know 7 wonders but I'd have never though on it for that, maybe we give a try, but I wonder if it can be fun with long turns. Thanks!

Comment: I will also take a look to Republic of Rome, I've never played it.

Comment: We really should have closed this question. Game Recommendations are not good fits for the Q&A format. Chat would be a better place.

Comment: Well, it's not so a "What's the best game for...?" question that uses to be answered with lists of subjective answers, the requirements are quite specific now. But it's fine to close it if you think it should have never existed here :)

Comment: I have heard good things about the games here. http://triton.ironhelmet.com/#landing They are real time so I think they meet your criteria. However I have never played them myself so I cannot be certain. Also a downside is that it seems to host private games you have to pay for a membership (which is why I have not tried them yet).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [A Game of Thrones](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/103343/a-game-of-thrones-the-board-game-second-edition) is such a game. While a complete elimination is possible, the game plays in 10 rounds, and it is very difficult to achieve a complete elimination.

Many people say the game plays similarly to Diplomacy.

> To begin the game, each player receives an army of Footman, Knight, Siege Engine, and Ship units, as well as a set of Order tokens and other necessary components. Each player also receives a deck of unique House Cards, which are used as leaders in battles against rival Houses.
>
> Each round in the game is made up of three phases: the Westeros Phase, the Planning Phase, and the Action Phase. The Westeros Phase represents special events and day-to-day activities in Westeros. There are three different Westeros Decks, and each denotes a different global action, potentially affecting all players.
>
> The Planning Phase is perhaps the most important. Here you secretly assign orders to all of your units by placing one order token face down on each area you control that contains at least one unit (Knight, Footman, Ship, or Siege Engine). This portion of the game emphasizes diplomacy and deduction. Can you trust the alliance that you made? Will you betray your ally and march upon him? Players may make promises to each other (for aid or peace, for example), but these promises are never binding. The result is tense and compelling negotiations, often ending in backstabbing worthy of Westeros!
>
> During the Action Phase, the orders are resolved and battle is entered! When armies meet in combat, they secretly choose one of their House cards to add strength to the battle. Finally, the Houses can consolidate their power in the areas they control and use that power in future turns to influence their position in the court of the Iron Throne and to stand against the wildling Hordes.

Comment: I know this game, and I really like it, I appreciate all the things it has in common with Diplomacy. But I think it doesn't fit so well with how we play diplomacy. In Game of Thrones you cannot declare your whole turn at once, and as in diplomacy, a player can be eliminated some time before the end of the game, that is one of the main things we'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

[Race for the Galaxy](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/28143/race-for-the-galaxy/) might fit the bill, though the game is so different from Diplomacy that it may not be what you have in mind.

Players simultaneously secretly choose (then reveal) the phases for a given turn. Each player simultaneously plays out each phase of that turn. Players cannot be eliminated from the game, but it is possible to fall so far behind that winning becomes pretty much impossible. However, playing a game takes around 30 minutes so being far behind in the last few minutes of a game isn't that big a deal.

Comment: The worst feature of this game is getting started. The iconography is dense and cumbersome. So most people (including me) feel totally lost first few games. Play at least 10 games before you decide whether or not you like this game. You won't after game 1.

Comment: @JaimeSoriano I'm not sure this is a good fit. The possible phases for each turn happen in a specific sequence (explore, develop, settle, consume, produce), everyone does every phase that anyone has picked, and what others choose each time is potentially relevant, so if you're playing asynchronously, you'll be chopping into pretty small bits with a lot of synchronization points.

Comment: Yes - this would be a poor game to play asynchronously, especially considering that it's a fast game. I think you'll get better answers to your question if you explicitly list the requirements in bullet points - I just reread the question and see how I didn't pick up that asynchronous was a requirement.

Comment: I have updated the question with more explicit requirements, thanks for all the contributons!